React Native Images Won't Render Using URI
My images won't render in my code, regardless of the fact that all other updates will immediately display after saving. I've tried locally hosted images too and the problem persists.
The images should load 1 per each Card, but none of the images display. The cards display fine. Please note even using local files the images do not load. I think this is some formatting issue or something from my end.
import React from 'react';

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Deck from './src/Deck';


const DATA = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Card #1', uri: 'http:...' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Card #2', uri: 'hhttp:...' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Card #3', uri: 'http:...' },
  { id: 4, text: 'Card #4', uri: 'http:...' },
  { id: 5, text: 'Card #5', uri: 'http:...' },
  { id: 6, text: 'Card #6', uri: 'http:...' },
  { id: 7, text: 'Card #7', uri: 'http:...' },
  { id: 8, text: 'Card #8', uri: 'http:...' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  renderCard(item) {
    return (
      <Card
        key={item.id}
        title={item.text}
        image={{ uri: item.uri }}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          I can customize the Card further.
        </Text>
        <Button
          icon={{ name: 'code' }}
          backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
          title="View Now!"
        />
      </Card>
      );
    }

  render () {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Deck 
        data={DATA}
        renderCard={this.renderCard}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default App;

I've attached my App.JS which I believe is at the root of the issue. Maybe I need to add styling components?

How about putting the uri directly instead of an object. image={item.uri }
